# How to do nothing while using replace() string method?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am working with some strings and I am removing some characters from them by using `replace()`, for example:

```
a = 'monsterr'
new_a = a.replace("rr", "r")
new_a
```

However, let's say that now I receive the following string:

In:

```
a = 'difference'
new_a = a.replace("rr", "r")
new_a
```

Out:

```
'difference'
```

How can I return nothing if my string doesnt contain `rr`? Is there anyway of just pass or return nothing? I tried to:

```
def check(a_str):
    if 'rr' in a_str:
        a_str = a_str.replace("rr", "r")
        return a_str
    else:
        pass
```

However, it doesn't work. The expected output would be for `monster`would be nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? `None`, the empty string `''`? The same string unmodified?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about "it doesnt work"

Comment: Why do you have `return a_str_5`? What is `a_str_5`?

Comment: @slider sorry I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `return`:

```
def check(a_str):
    if 'rr' in a_str:
        a_str = a_str.replace("rr", "r")
        return a_str
```

For list comprehension:

```
a = ["difference", "hinderr"]
x = [i.replace("rr", "r") for i in a]
```

Comment: You don't really need `else: return` if you just intend to return `None`. Beside `pass` in the original code should also result in returning `None`.

Comment: Isn't the `else` clause unnecessary if they want `None` returned when the condition isn't fulfilled??

Comment: Is there any way of doing it as a comprehension list?

Comment: @slider absolutely right. I also quietly included fixing the wrong variable name. Code works so its up to OP

Comment: @J.Doe i've added an example for list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

Just as a little *easter egg*, I figured I'd include this little gem as an option as well, if only because of your question:

> How can I return nothing if my string doesnt contain rr? Is there anyway of just pass or return nothing?

Using boolean operators, you could take the `if` line completely out of `check()`.

```
def check(text, dont_want='rr', want='r'):
    replacement = text.replace(dont_want, want)

    return replacement != text and replacement or None
    #checks if there was a change after replacing,
    #if True:    returns replacement
    #if False:   returns None

test = "differrence"
check(test)
#difference

test = "difference"
check(test)
#None
```

*Consider this `un-pythonic` or not, it's another option.* Plus it's along the lines of his question.

*"return none if string doesn't contain rr"*

For those that don't know how or why this works, *(and/or enjoy learning cool python tricks but don't know this)* then here's the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/lambda.html) page explaining boolean operators.

**P.S.**

*Technically speaking, it is `un-pythonic` due to it being a `ternary` operation. This does go against the "Zen of Python" ~ [`import this`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3) but coming from `C` style languages I enjoy them.*